# ¿Son aceptables las preguntas que puedan ser etiquetadas como: diversión, ejemplos, etc.?

Tags: discusión

Las preguntas que pueden entrar en categorías del tipo: diversión, ejemplos, etc., que son generalmente preguntas para intercambio de experiencias, ejemplos, trabajos y a veces diversión, son permitidas en otros sitios de la red StackExchange como [TeX.SX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/), claro que la temática y objetivos de esos sitios pueden ser muy distintos al nuestro. Pero, ¿podría estar mal visto e incluso podría ser borrada una pregunta que caiga en categorías como estas?, una pregunta como por ejemplo: **Ejemplos de generación de secuencias de números primos utilizando POO**.

Pienso que estas preguntas, a pesar de que tienen infinitas respuestas, pueden servir como un recurso útil para muchos programadores principiantes, y por qué no, para divertirnos conforme crece el sitio.

Comment: ¿Algo como http://codegolf.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @JhonAlx Sí, se parece a eso.

Answer (score 2):

Por lo que tengo entendido de la creación y crecimiento de *Stack Overflow em Português*, la idea es:

> Haz de este site el site que te gustaría ver cuando crezca.

Ya llegará el momento de cerrar y borrar preguntas populares pero *off-topic*, y en que tengamos que hacernos la pregunta: [*¿Cuáles son temas que deben hacer parte de nuestro site?*](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/264/quais-assuntos-devem-fazer-parte-do-nosso-foco-on-topic)

Por ahora, mientras sea nuestro [*on-topic default*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) y sea bien explicada y redactada, creo que vale experimentar y poner nuestros expertos a prueba con:

> - un problema específico de programación, o
> - un algoritmo de software, o
> - herramientas de software comúnmente utilizadas por programadores; y es
> - un problema práctico, que tiene respuesta y único al desarrollo de software

Me parece que lo que [hay que evitar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) especialmente es:

> - cada respuesta es igualmente válida: “¿Cuál es tu ______ favorito?”

<sub>Relacionado: [***Good Subjective, Bad Subjective – Stack Overflow Blog***](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)</sub>